# Tool to determine filesystem on CompactFlash media

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, removable-storage

I have a CompactFlash card that is used in a custom piece of hardware. WAV files are written to it. Windows doesn't recognize the media and wants to format it, which rules out FAT 16/32, NTFS, UDF, etc. Is there a Windows tool that can determine what filesystem the media is using and possible read the contents?

I've tried dskprobe.exe, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unix file command can read block-special files and identify filesystems on them. You might be able to get a port of that which runs on windows. If not, you could always boot from a live linux cd and run the command

```
file -s /dev/cfdevice
```

where cfdevice is the actual device name for your compact flash. It'll probably be sda or sdb or something like that.

Comment: can't run a file port if the media doesn't mount in Windows.  The live linux cd might be my only option at this point.  Thanks for the heads up.